# How to make short url in wordpress with custom taxonomy and custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I had a struct like this:

http://example.com/products-category/products/vietnamese-hair/single-drawn-hair/

How can I make this URL shorter, like: http://example.com/vietnamese-hair/single-drawn-hair?

**EDIT:** Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe/$ /wp-content/plugins/email-newsletter/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you tried it with mod_rewrite?

Comment: Im new with htaccess and i dont know how to write a htaccess for this.

Comment: I tried many plugin for this but it didnt work.Im using the basic htaccess of wordpress.

Comment: without seening your htaccess it is not possible to give a good answer

Answer (score 0):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe/$ /wp-content/plugins/email-newsletter/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```